# how to resolve file path reference to a file in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, resolve, filepath

hi
how to resolve file path reference to a file in asp.net mvc. Suppose I have an image file in the content/image/img.jpg". How do i get the physical path of the file in asp.net mvc.

Comment: ~/content/image/img.jpg should work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the [MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutilitybase.mappath.aspx) method:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string physicalPath = Server.MapPath("~/content/image/img.jpg");
    ...
}
```

and if you are inside a view you don't need the physical path but a relative path taking into account the virtual directory so you should be using Url helpers:

```
<img src="<%= Url.Content("~/content/image/img.jpg") %>" alt="" />
```

And if you are inside some other layer of the application which doesn't have direct access to the HttpContext you shouldn't be getting any physical path to a file, this path should be injected/passed to the corresponding layer.